# I'm working in Kotlin and not sure how, to recode from if/else if to when statement

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
  if ( 32 < 47) {
    println("47")
 }
 
 else if (0 < 20) {
    println("Very Cold weather")
 
 }
 else if (21 < 40) {
    println("Cold")

}

  if (41 < 60) {
    println("Normal")
    
}



}
```

So, I am really new at this and lost on how to recode from if/else if to when statements I have tried everything I could think of.

Comment: Can you provide a better example? `when` does only make sense if you have a variable and not fixed numbers.

Comment: From context, I assume the checks should be against ranges, so `if (temperature in 21 until 40){println("Cold")}` etc, as it is the code doesnt make sense, the first wil always be true since 32 is in fact smaller than 47.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are the requirements here? What do you want your program to _do_?

Answer (score 0):

Each condition (what's in the parentheses) goes on a new line with `->` after it.

I'm assuming it was a mistake in your program that the last `if` is missing the `else` word before it.

Note that the compiler will give you a warning about unreachable code. This is because 32 is guaranteed to be less than 47, so it doesn't really make sense that you have other conditions after that, or that you're using `if` or `when` at all. Writing `if (32 < 47)` is no different than writing `if (true)`, which is nonsensical.

```
fun main() {
    when {
        32 < 47 -> println("47")
        0 < 20 -> println("Very Cold weather")
        21 < 40 -> println("Cold")
        41 < 60 -> println("Normal")
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the else was left out because the output needs to be 47 Normal your answer did help me with the output being 47 but I get an error saying Compiler won't reduce this expression to {0} in future. Please replace it with Boolean literal my output needs to say 47 Normal

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand what you’re asking for. The logic doesn’t make sense to begin with because the first condition is based on constant values and will always be true.

Comment: so I have to recode this fun main() {
  if ( 32 < 47) {
    println("47")
 }
 
 else if (0 < 20) {
    println("Very Cold weather")
 
 }
 else if (21 < 40) {
    println("Cold")


}


  if (41 < 60) {
    println("Normal")
   
}



} with when statement my output ended up being 47 Normal which was what was expected I need the same output just recoded with when statement. not sure what to do.

Comment: The code you’re describing doesn’t make sense because all the conditions will always be true. You might as well delete all of it and write `println("47 normal")`